# JSTL import tag throws java.lang.IllegalStateException with relative URL

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, jstl, stripes

In a Java web application I am using the Stripes framework on Jboss 4.2.3. In my JSP when I use

```
<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/contextPath/txts/someID" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

It works great and the the contents are included in the output HTML. However, this does not work

```
<c:import url="/txts/someID" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

and it throws this error (the whole stack is too big to paste here, so I include the first few lines):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected internal error during &lt;import&gt: Target servlet called getOutputStream(), then getWriter()
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ImportSupport.java:492)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.action.StreamingResolution.stream(StreamingResolution.java:443)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.action.StreamingResolution.execute(StreamingResolution.java:240)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper$7.intercept(DispatcherHelper.java:508)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:158)
at org.stripesstuff.plugin.security.SecurityInterceptor.interceptResolutionExecution(SecurityInterceptor.java:225)
at org.stripesstuff.plugin.security.SecurityInterceptor.intercept(SecurityInterceptor.java:129)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.HttpCacheInterceptor.intercept(HttpCacheInterceptor.java:99)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.intercept(BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.java:113)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.wrap(ExecutionContext.java:74)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.executeResolution(DispatcherHelper.java:502)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.executeResolution(DispatcherServlet.java:286)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:170)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: According to the spec the /contextPath should not be included unless it is different from the current one.

Comment: copy your servlet code to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if the StreamingResolution is opened with a Reader, then it (naturally) opens a Writer to stream the output out. The c:import tag doesn't care, and simply calls getOutputStream on the response.

So, to mitigate this you should not use a Reader for your StreamingResolution, rather you need to create the StreamingResolution with a InputStream.

The other option is to override the StreamingResolution.stream() method.

Stripes is basically "doing the right thing" for you, but the c:import is raining on your parade.

Thankfully, you have control over Stripes actions. Not so much over c:imports actions.

Comment: I am using the constructor where I supply an InputStream. Should I override the StreamingResolution.stream() with response.getOutputStream().write(...) instead?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in JSTL, but in the target servlet. The exception message is clear - your should not call `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` for the same response.

Comment: On the target servlet I am using a standard mechanism to stream content in Stripes using [StreamingResolution](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/StreamingResolution.html) using the second constructor where I supply an InputStream. Could this be a flaw in the way this mechanism works?